# i have a problem with emguCV in Visual studio

Tags: c#

I'm french and not very easy to write in english so i apologize for this.
I need to use emguCV for my projet but i have many problem. I have 2 PC, one is a windows 7 professional 64 bits and other is a windows 10 x64. On the first PC emguCV working normaly no problem but in the second PC i use visual studio 2019 and emguCV 3.4.3.3016 but when run i have a this error

`Unable to load DLL 'cvextern': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`

and in windows exit have this
`LoadLibraryEx C:\Users\adartois\Desktop\Nouveau dossier\WindowsFormsApp10\WindowsFormsApp10\bin\Debug\x86\cvextern.dll failed with error code 126: Le module spécifié est introuvable`

For solve this error a test :

- In my project in bin/debug i put 2 folder x64 and x86 from emguCV 3.4.3.3016.
- In preference i put Emgu.CV.UI and Emgu.CV.World
- With my perso PC in windows 10 i never have this problem

this is the code for test

```
OpenFileDialog Openfile = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (Openfile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Image<Bgr, byte> My_Image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(Openfile.FileName);
                pictureBox1.Image = My_Image.ToBitmap();
            }
```

The error happen due to line 4 (Image<Bgr, byte>)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend updating Emgu to a later version. 3.4.3 is from 2018, and there are later versions available.

I would also suggest using nuget to add the library (Tools\Nuget Package Manager\Manage nuget packages for solution). This lets visual studio add any required dependencies automatically.

You probably want the `Emgu.CV.runtime.windows` and the `Emgu.CV.UI` packages. I'm not sure what `Emgu.CV.World` refers to, I cannot find any references to such a package.

I'm far from an expert with regards to Emgu, and calling native code is a fairly frequent source of issues. But referencing the runtime package just worked for me. There is probably some magic going on under the hood.

Also, windows 7 has reached end of life a fairly long time ago, I would not expect all modern software to work on it.